WebGL Context Error on iOS Browsers Device
I'm encountering a frustrating issue with my Godot 4.3 game exported for the web. When I try to run it on an iOS device using Safari and other browsers, I get a WebGL context error. I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm still stumped.
Here's a breakdown of what I've done so far:

Checked WebGL 2.0 support: I've confirmed that my browser and device support WebGL 2.0.
Verified export settings: I've double-checked the export settings in Godot to ensure they're correct for web exports.
Tested on other devices: The game runs fine on Android and desktop browsers.
Tried different browsers: I've tested with Chrome and Firefox on iOS, but the same issue persists.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? I'm open to any suggestions or troubleshooting steps.
Thanks in advance!
